# Como ler apenas os números do FormatDataTime

Tags: delphi, data, firemonkey

Precisava saber qual a hora atual do computador e comparar com valores no banco de dados, exemplo:

```
'agenda.hora >= "' + formatdatatime('hh:ss',now) + ";
```

Acontece que tanto no banco quanto o formate vão me retornar uma string, a do banco eu consigo converter para integer, mas não sei como converter o resultado do `FormatDataTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Usando a unit DateUtils, tem acesso a funçoes como a HourOf(TDatetime). Pode fazer

```
valorHora:=HourOf(now);
```

e usar este valor como um int

Answer (score 1):

Vou dar o exemplo de duas formas de o fazer, na primeira uso a função `FormatDataTime`, exemplo:

```
var VHora, VMinuto: integer;
Begin
  VHora := StrToInt(FormatDataTime('hh',now));  
  VMinuto := StrToInt(FormatDataTime('nn',now));
End;
```

A segunda forma tal como mencionado pelo @TiagoRodrigues, vamos usar a função `HourOf` e `MinuteOf`, exemplo:

```
var VHora, VMinuto: integer;
Begin
  VHora := HourOf(now); 
  VMinuto := MinuteOf(now);
End;
```

Na pergunta está a usar apenas horas e minutos, se precisar segundos avise que edito a resposta. Alguma dúvida mais avise.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma função chamada **DecodeDateTime**, que utiliza a unit **DateUtils** e ela quebra as partes da data e hora, assim você consegue trabalhar com cada elemento. Segue um exemplo.

```
procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  wAno, wMes, wDia : Word;
  wHora, wMinuto, wSegundos, wMilissegundo : Word;
  iHour, iMinuto: Integer;
begin
  DecodeDateTime(Now(), wAno, wMes, wDia, wHora, wMinuto, wSegundos, wMilissegundo);

  iHour := wHora;
  iMinuto := wMinuto;
end;
```